# How to read file from file system during Maven build of module

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project A (packaged as a pom) containing Maven module project B (packaged as a jar). 
Project B is also physically in the root of project A.

When B is being built, a plugin indirectly uses my code (inside B) to access a property file in its src/main/resources location.

When I build project B directly (mvn clean install) the code can easily find that file by using `new File("src/main/resources/foo.properties");`

However when I try to build project A, it first will try to build the module B, and in that case it cannot find the property file.

Apart from the 'new File' variant, I have tried using
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/foo.properties");`

and I tried using Spring:

`Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("src/main/resources/foo.properties");`

Both also with a "/" prefix. But the file simply cannot be found.

Why is that? Might it be looking for the file in the root of A? Is it possible to find the file in module B when building A?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, the workaround is clearly to change your `new File("src/main/resources/foo.properties");` to `new File("../ModuleB/src/main/resources/foo.properties");` or whatever your folder structure is, but I guess thats not what you want? ;-)

Comment: No, I want the file to be found when either building A (and inherent B) or B by itself. Also I would expect Maven to handle B as a isolated build in both cases.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that if building module B alone (how, by calling mvn inside the directory where module B's pom.xml is?), it works, but not when building B during a multi-module build together with module A? So the issue is when module B is building, not module A?

Comment: When building B (by calling mvn inside B) works perfectly, but when building A (by calling mvn inside A) doesn't work, because module B cannot be built (because the file cannot be found in that case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new File("src/main/resources/foo.properties");
```

This is a path relative to the working directory. The working directory is wherever you called maven. So that's why it won't work when calling maven anywhere other than the directory of module B.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/foo.properties");
```

This won't work because the classpath is where maven put the classes, that is, `target/classes`.

What you need to do is add this file as resource in the maven build, then use the `getResourceAsStream` idea with the correct path. Since you used the standard maven layout, you probably don't need to anything and just use

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
```

Comment: I now realize I was unnecessary trying to access the src folder; I should have tried to access the file in the target folder. When removing the 'src/main/resources' part, and just referring to the remainder ('foo.properties') I can sucesfully access the file using getResource or getResourceAsStream. Thanks.